# How to Get the Largest Key of each Spark Partition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

If we use `.reduce(max)` then we will get the largest key in the whole RDD. I know this reduce will operate on all partitions and then reduce those items sent by each partition. But how can we get back the largest key of every partition? Write a function for `.mapPartitions()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
rdd.mapParitions(iter => Iterator(iter.reduce(Math.max)))
```

or

```
rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iter: [max(iter)])
```

In streaming use this with `DStream.trasform`.

Comment: Thank you and I have another question. If there are 3 largest keys and they are equal with each other, then rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iter: [max(iter)]) only get 1 back, so how can we get these 3 largest keys together?